# Google-Calendar API - get offset of the default calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to create an event in Google Calendar using its API setting the start-end time to be `14:00-15:00` according the calendar's timeZone. Following this [reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) I can create an appointment but I have to pass dateTime formatted according to [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339). It demands to know the offset of the calendar's timeZone.

So following this [reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) I get the default calendar instance, but it has the name of the `timeZone` without the offset.

What is the way to create an event on a specific date at `14:00-15:00` according the default calendar's timeZone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the default calendar timezone would be to use [Zulu timezone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z) which means it "has no offset from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)" - +8 UTC , those kind of stuff.

Sample from the [Events: insert Try-it](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert):

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-06-15T15:00:00Z"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-06-15T14:00:00Z"   
  },
  "description": "test"
}
```

But if in turn, you want to use a specific timezone, remove the Z and add the timeZone property

```
 {
      "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-06-15T15:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Singapore"
      },
      "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-06-15T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Singapore"
      },
      "description": "Singapore"
    }
```

Hope this small sample helps.